# JS string destructuring: rest parameter returning inconsistent data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructor, ecma, rest-parameters

Consider the following examples

An old project:

```
const [x, ...y] = "text";
console.log(x) // "t"
console.log(y) // "ext"
```

A new project based on [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

```
const [x, ...y] = "text";
console.log(x) // "t"
console.log(y) // ["e", "x", "t"]
```

I'm not sure why `y` is returning a string (`"ext"`) for the old project, where it's an array of characters (`["e", "x", "t"]`) for the new project. Is it something to do with different JS versions?

Note: Both result were extracted after running webpack dev server.

Comment: The second output is the one that the spec would require... (rest params should always create an array, no matter, what was destructured)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in [babel website](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) you can see that your code based on es2015-loose convert to this code so output of this code is same with your old project

```
"use strict";

var _text = "text",
    x = _text[0],
    y = _text.slice(1);

console.log(x); // "t"

console.log(y); // "ext"
```